# Tendermint vs Algorand - Similarities and Differences

Tags: consensus

The core of Algorand uses a Byzantine agreement protocol called BA⋆ that scales to many users while Tendermint is based on a modified version of
the DLS protocol which is resilient up to 1/3 of Byzantine participants.

Am trying to decide between both -- any inputs?